# ¿Cómo imprimir cada comentario con su post?

Tags: php, html5, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un pequeño sistema de hacer posts en mi sitio que estoy creando. Cada posts lo imprimo con "echo" de PHP.

Todo va funcionando de maravilla al principio(imprimirlo). Pero el problema surge cuando intento hacerle comentarios a ese post.

**¿Cuál es el problema?**

Cuando escribo el primer comentario este se queda con su post, pero cuando escribo el segundo comentario en ese mismo post ocurre que en vez de salir el segundo comentario debajo del primero, me clona o me imprime otro post con ese comentario(el segundo.) No se si entienden.

**Tabla Personas**

```
   -------   -------    ----------    ---------    --------   --------
    ID      nombre      apellido     correo       password    Fotos
   ------    ------     ---------     --------     --------    ------
```

**Tabla Posts**

```
        -------   -------    ----------    ---------    
        Id_post    User_Id    Titulo        Contenido     
         ------    ------     ---------     --------
```

**Tabla comentarios**

```
     -------   ---------    ----------   ---------     --------   
     id_com    contenido      fecha      id_usuario    id_post    
     ------    --------     ---------     --------     --------
```

**Tabla posts_votos**

```
     -------   ---------    ----------   ---------     --------   
     Id        Id_post      id_usuario    puntos        fecha
     ------    --------     ---------     --------     --------
```

Pondré el código:

Como pueden ver hago una consulta de 3 tablas utilizando Join.

```
  $query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT 
      posts.Id_post, 
      posts.Titulo, 
      posts.Contenido, 
      personas.Id,
      personas.Fotos,
      personas.nombre,
      personas.apellido,
      posts_votos.id_usuario,
      posts_votos.puntos,
      posts_votos.id_post,
      comentarios.contenido
 FROM posts
 LEFT JOIN  comentarios
   ON comentarios.id_post = posts.Id_post AND posts.User_Id = 
       comentarios.id_usuario


 LEFT JOIN  posts_votos
   ON posts_votos.id_post = posts.Id_post AND posts.User_Id = 
      posts_votos.id_usuario

LEFT JOIN personas
   ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id
     WHERE posts.User_Id = $my_id ORDER BY id DESC") or die('Error: ' . 
   mysqli_error($conn));




  while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {


       $id_user = $posts_filas['Id'];
       $code = $posts_filas['Id_post'];
       $title = $posts_filas['Titulo'];
       $contenido  = $posts_filas['Contenido'];
       # code...
       $contenido2  = $posts_filas['contenido'];
      $points  = $posts_filas['puntos'];
```

### Desde aquí se imprime cada post:

```
  echo '<div style ="margin-bottom:20px;" class="POSTED"> 



  <div class="post_p1">
   <div class="Header_post">
    <div class="orden_post">



      <div class="orden_post_content">
       <a href="#"><p class="aaaaa">'. $posts_filas['nombre'].' 
        '.$posts_filas['apellido'].'</p></a>
         </div>



     <div class="orden_post_content_pic">
       <a href="perfil.php?=id"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="'. 
         $posts_filas['Fotos'].'"> </img></a>
     </div>







       </div>
        <div class="boton_eliminar_post">
           <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-
              hidden="true"></i></a>
               </div>
                </div>


       <div class="post_titulo">' . htmlentities($title) . '</div>'



    .'<div class="post_contenido"><div class="post_contenido_content">' . 
        htmlentities($contenido) .'</div>' . '</div>'
        .'<div class="points_post">
            <div class="content_points">


            <div class="orden_post">
                <div class="orden_post_content"><a href="javascript:void(0)" 
    ><span><i style="font-size:24px;" class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-
     hidden="true"></i></span></a></div>
                <div id="share_link" class="orden_post_content"><a 
     href="javascript:void(0)" ><i class="fa fa-share-square" aria-
     hidden="true"></i>Compartir</a></div>
                <div class="orden_post_content"><a 
      href="javascript:void(0)"><span>'.$posts_filas['puntos']. ' 
      </span>globos</a></div>

            </div>


       </div></div>'












 .'<form id="form_comentarios" method="POST">


    <ul style="padding:0;">
    <li class="alinear_elementos_post">

            <input type="hidden" name="eid" 
               value="'.$posts_filas['Id_post'].'">
                 <img width="35px" height="35px" src="'. 
                    $posts_filas['Fotos'].'"> </img> 
                      </li>


    <li id="textbox-align" class="alinear_elementos_post">
            <input type="text" class="campo_comentario" 
        name="comment_content" rows="2" cols="44" style="text-align:center;"
         placeholder="Escribe un comentario." required></input>
             </li>


     <li class="alinear_elementos_post">
            <input class="boton_campo_comentario" type="submit" 
                  name="comentar"></input>


                      </li>

    </ul>


       </form>'.'
         <p class="aaaaa"> '.$posts_filas['contenido'].'</p>'
           .'</div>'




       .'<div class="post_p2">








      <a onclick="('.$posts_filas['Id_post'].')" data-
      id='.$posts_filas['Id_post'].' href="javascript:void(0)" 
      class="globes_post_giving"><div class="alinear_boton_balloons"><img
          class="img_style" src="img/globo-s.png"></img></div></a>















         <a href="#" class="globes_post_res">#</a>
         </div>'




      .'</div>';

  }




$contar = mysqli_num_rows($query_buscar_posts);



         if($contar == 0) {

      echo "<div class='No_post'>
      <div class='message_empty_post'>Aun no has puesto nada aqui!</div><br>

   <div class='contenido_no_post'><i class='fa fa-frown-o' aria-
      hidden='true'></i></div>
   <div class='footer_empty_post'>
         <a href=''>Editar mi perfil</a>
         <a href=''>Ir a mi perfil</a>
         </div>
   </div>";
  }
   ?>
```

Cada post que imprimo se ve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema está en los comentarios. El primero sale de acorde al post que yo se lo ponga y el segundo me imprime otro post igual, cosa que no debería ser así.

Comment: Si haces un join de post y comentarios, tendrás siempre en cada fila el post original y cada comentario, duplicando el post tantas veces como comentarios tengas. Debes generar 2 consultas separadas, la primera para el post, y la segunda para sacar todos los comentarios relacionados con el post. O bien dejarlo así y mostrar el post solo la primera vez (pero es más cutre)

Comment: @Muriano me podrias ayudar a implementarlo de esa forma? es que no se como empezar,lo que quiero decir es que de que forma lo coloco?

Comment: Podrías colocar la estructura de las 3 tablas por favor? con esa info puedo darte la solución que pides.

Comment: @J.Correa listo.Ya he editado mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, vamos a ver, como pides lo he montado en dos consultas, una para los posts y su info, y otra para los comentarios. Te adjunto el codigo completo, es posible que haya algun error de sintaxis pues yo no soy de php y tampoco se puede probar sin las tablas, asi que prueba y me comentas a ver que te sale.

```
<?php
$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT posts.Id_post, posts.Titulo,  posts.Contenido, personas.Id, personas.Fotos,personas.nombre,personas.apellido,posts_votos.id_usuario, posts_votos.puntos,posts_votos.id_post
                                            FROM posts
                                            LEFT JOIN  posts_votos
                                                ON posts_votos.id_post = posts.Id_post AND posts.User_Id = posts_votos.id_usuario
                                            LEFT JOIN personas
                                                ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id
                                            WHERE posts.User_Id = $my_id ORDER BY id DESC"
 ) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));



$query_buscar_comentarios = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT comentarios.contenido
                                                 FROM posts
                                                 LEFT JOIN  comentarios
                                                    ON comentarios.id_post = posts.Id_post AND posts.User_Id = comentarios.id_usuario
                                                 WHERE posts.User_Id = $my_id 
                                                 ORDER BY id DESC"
) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));

    $contar = mysqli_num_rows($query_buscar_posts);
    if($contar == 0) {
        echo "<div class='No_post'>
                <div class='message_empty_post'>Aun no has puesto nada aqui!</div><br>
                <div class='contenido_no_post'>
                    <i class='fa fa-frown-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                </div>
                <div class='footer_empty_post'>
                    <a href=''>Editar mi perfil</a>
                    <a href=''>Ir a mi perfil</a>
                </div>
              </div>";
    }else{
         while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {


               $id_user = $posts_filas['Id'];
               $code = $posts_filas['Id_post'];
               $title = $posts_filas['Titulo'];
               $points  = $posts_filas['puntos'];
               $contenido  = $posts_filas['Contenido'];
               $comentarios=array();
               while ($comentarios_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_comentarios)) {
                    array_push($comentarios,$comentarios_filas['contenido'];);
               }

              $post='<div style ="margin-bottom:20px;" class="POSTED">'. 
                  '<div class="post_p1">'.
                    '<div class="Header_post">'.
                        '<div class="orden_post">'.
                            '<div class="orden_post_content">'.
                                '<a href="#"><p class="aaaaa">'. $posts_filas['nombre'].' '.$posts_filas['apellido'].'</p></a>'.
                            '</div>'.
                            '<div class="orden_post_content_pic">'.
                                '<a href="perfil.php?=id"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="'. $posts_filas['Fotos'].'"> </img></a>'.
                            '</div>'.
                       '</div>'.
                       '<div class="boton_eliminar_post">'.
                           '<a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'.
                       '</div>'.
                    '</div>'.
                    '<div class="post_titulo">' . htmlentities($title) . '</div>'.
                    '<div class="post_contenido">'.
                        '<div class="post_contenido_content">' . htmlentities($contenido) .'</div>'.
                    '</div>'.
                    '<div class="points_post">'.
                        '<div class="content_points">'.
                            '<div class="orden_post">'.
                                '<div class="orden_post_content">'.
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0)">'.
                                        '<span>'.
                                            '<i style="font-size:24px;" class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.
                                        '</span>'.
                                    '</a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div id="share_link" class="orden_post_content">'.
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" >'.
                                        '<i class="fa fa-share-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>Compartir'.
                                    '</a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div class="orden_post_content">'.
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0)">'.
                                        '<span>'.$posts_filas['puntos']. '</span>globos'.
                                    '</a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                            '</div>'.
                       '</div>'.
                    '</div>'.
                    '<form id="form_comentarios" method="POST">'.
                        '<ul style="padding:0;">'.
                            '<li class="alinear_elementos_post">'.
                                '<input type="hidden" name="eid" value="'.$posts_filas['Id_post'].'">'.
                                '<img width="35px" height="35px" src="'.$posts_filas['Fotos'].'"> </img> '.
                            '</li>'.
                            '<li id="textbox-align" class="alinear_elementos_post">'.
                                '<input type="text" class="campo_comentario" name="comment_content" rows="2" cols="44" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="Escribe un comentario." required></input>'.
                            '</li>'.
                            '<li class="alinear_elementos_post">'.
                                '<input class="boton_campo_comentario" type="submit" name="comentar"></input>'.
                            '</li>'.
                        '</ul>'.
                    '</form>';

                    for($x = 0; $x < count($comentarios); $x++) {
                        $post=$post.'<p class="aaaaa"> '.$comentarios[$x].'</p><br>';
                    }

                    $post=$post.'</div>'.
                 '<div class="post_p2">'.
                    '<a onclick="('.$posts_filas['Id_post'].')" data-id='.$posts_filas['Id_post'].' href="javascript:void(0)" class="globes_post_giving">'.
                        '<div class="alinear_boton_balloons">'.
                            '<img class="img_style" src="img/globo-s.png"></img>'.
                        '</div>'.
                    '</a>'.
                    '<a href="#" class="globes_post_res">#</a>'.
                 '</div>'.
                '</div>';

                echo $post;
            }      
       }


?>
```

Comment: Intentare probar este código,aunque ya lo tengo implementado de otra forma(llamando los comentarios hacia una ventana modal,osea,los comentarios según el posts que yo seleccione).Pero no esta de mas probar este código. Gracias!!!

Comment: Si te funciona y te gusta, marca como respuesta aceptada ;) y si no, siempre es un placer ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Para dividir la query en dos partes, yo lo haría así:

Primero obtengo todos los posts y sus votos relacionados:

```
// Obtienes todos los posts y sus campos
$query_posts = 
  "SELECT
    *
  FROM
    posts AS P
  JOIN
    posts_votos AS PV
  ON
    P.id_post = PV.id_post
  WHERE
    P.user_id = $_SESSION[user_id]"; 
// O de donde quiera que almacenes la identificación del ususario o.O

$result_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $query_posts);
```

Luego recorro uno a uno con un while. Por cada iteración del while, hago otra consulta sql para obtener los comentarios y los usuarios relacionados al post que esté recorriendo el ciclo:

```
while ($post_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_posts)) {

  $query_comentarios = "
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      comentarios AS C
    JOIN
      personas AS P
    ON
      C.id_usuario = P.id_personas
    WHERE
      C.id_post = $post_row[id_post]";

    $result_comentarios = mysqli_query($conn, $query_comentarios);

    // Este array almacenará todos los comentarios del post actual del primer while
    $array_comentarios = array();

    while ( $comentario_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_comentarios) ) {
      array_push($array_comentarios, $comentario_row);
    }

  // Aquí imprimes el post y sus comentarios
```

Hasta aquí ya obtienes la información, ahora sólo tienes que imprimirla. Veo que tienes mucho html y allí insertas php. En este punto, donde puse el comentario de "Aquí imprimes" colocarías tu html.

La verdad es que es un spaguetti y no es estético el código, quizá consideres hacer una segunda versión del mismo donde trates de separar lo más posible el html y el php.

Algo que podrías implementar es separar las acciones por funciones. Es decir, crear una función para obtener todos los posts, otra para obtener los comentarios:

```
function get_all_posts(){
  $$query_posts = 
  "SELECT
    *
  FROM
    posts AS P
  JOIN
    posts_votos AS PV
  ON
    P.id_post = PV.id_post";

  $result_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $query_posts);

  return $result_posts;
}

function get_coments( $id_post){
  $query_comentarios = "
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      comentarios AS C
    JOIN
      personas AS P
    ON
      C.id_usuario = P.id_personas
    WHERE
      C.id_post = $id_post";

    $result_comentarios = mysqli_query($conn, $query_comentarios);

    return $result_comentarios;
}
```

Aquí incluyes las funciones si quieres separarlas en un archivo aparte.

```
$result_posts = get_all_posts();

while ($post_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_posts)) {

  $result_comentarios = get_coments($post_row[id_post]);

  $array_comentarios = array();

  while ( $comentario_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_comentarios) ) {
    array_push($array_comentarios, $comentario_row);
  }

  // Imprimes el post y sus comentarios 

}
```

Y como te digo, ya sólo agregas el html que quieras imprimir. Si tienes dudas comentas. Saludos.

**Nota:**
Para que cada comentario sea mostrado al post que corresponde, revisa que al insertarlo lo esté haciendo con el id del post en cuestión, sino lo imprimirá donde no es, si es que lo imprime.

Edité la primera query ($query_posts) para obtener los votos relacionados con el post.

Comment: .Disculpa,pero hay campos que no se estan consultando,por ejemplo:nombre,apellido,Fotos

Comment: Ademas olvide poner otra tabla,pero que en la consulta SQL que puse al principio estan puestos esos campos.La tabla se llama Posts_votos

Comment: Ok, sobre los campos, en las consultas está el asterisco (*), o sea que debe devolver todos los campos de las tablas referenciadas. Puedes hacer un test con la query en phpmyadmin o en lo que estés usando para ejecutar directamente la query. 

Y de la otra tabla no mencionada, ya la vi, ¿Cómo le harías si ya estás obteniendo todos los posts y comentarios? 

Haré el cambio en la respuesta.

Comment: estoy obteniendo todos los post,pero vacios.

Comment: Podrías colocar la estructura de la tabla posts_votos y su relación con posts?

Comment: Creo que lo mejor seria como estaba antes.Porque?Porque segun lo que me has dado,me esta imprimiendo todos los posts,y según la consulta que yo tenia antes,me mostraba solo los posts del usuario logueado(como deseo).

Comment: Como creas que es mejor, no tenía en cuenta ese detalle :v   pero es muy sencillo de implementar, si acaso agregar dos o tres palabras en la query del post (haciendo un WHERE) ver el código...

Comment: Has visto la aplicacion de xbox en windows 10?Esa aplicacion tiene algo similar(en funcionamiento)a lo que quiero

Comment: No la he visto. He realizado el código según lo que entendí, en realidad no es difícil lo que quieres hacer, sólo necesitas un repaso a SQL. Si tienes todas tus tablas relacionadas con llaves, obtener información de cada una es relativamente fácil. Sin embargo, mi falta de comprensión de tu petición no me permite dar una respuesta satisfactoria al parecer :( Suerte con ello, saludos.

Comment: Ahora que veo este código después de un tiempo, estamos haciendo N + 1 consultas sql y en el peor de los casos podría haber un grave problema de performance, lo mejor sería una sola query que ya tenga los datos relacionados :think emoji *

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres separar tu consulta SQL en dos consultas SQL diferentes debes implementar algún método para detectar "nuevos mensajes":

```
$anterior = false;
while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {
  $id_user = $posts_filas['Id'];
  $code = $posts_filas['Id_post'];
  $title = $posts_filas['Titulo'];
  $contenido  = $posts_filas['Contenido'];
  /* Resto de código de asignación de variables */
  if ($anterior !== $code) 
    $anterior = $code;
    /* Aquí enviamos al navegador el HTML sólo del mensaje */
    echo '<div style ="margin-bottom:20px;" class="POSTED">...'; /* etc */
  }
  /* Ahora enviamos el HTML sólo de una respuesta */
  echo '<p class="aaaaa"> ',
    htmlspecialchars($posts_filas['contenido']),
    '</p>'; /* etc */
}
```

En tu caso es sencillo implementarlo porque no hay un "padre" que contenga tanto al mensaje como a los comentarios, en caso contrario habría que crear código adicional para hacer frente a ese inconveniente.

Aún así hay un método alternativo que sería hacer una primera pasada a los datos devueltos por tu consulta para guardarlos en una matriz asociativa, donde el primer nivel sea un mensaje y un elemento de él contenga los comentarios:

```
$datos = [];
while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {
  $id_user = $posts_filas['Id'];
  if (!isset($datos[$id_user])) {
    $datos[$id_user]['code'] = $posts_filas['Id_post'];
    $datos[$id_user]['title'] = $posts_filas['Titulo'];
    /* etc ... */
  }
  $datos[$id_user]['contenido'][]  = $posts_filas['Contenido'];
}
```

De esta manera tendrás un elemento en `$datos` por cada mensaje y un elemento en el índice `contenido` por cada comentario. Con dos `foreach` (uno para los mensajes y otro para los comentarios de cada mensaje) podrías generar el HTML de tu foro.

Comment: Entonces Con el primer método me funcionara?No me repetira los posts?

Comment: Con el primer método no te repetirá los posts ya que en caso de que se repita el mismo `Id_post` se salta la parte en la que vuelve a "pintar" el HTML del post y sólo pinta el HTML del comentario.

Comment: en esta linea :---------------------------------------------------------echo '<form id="form_comentarios" method="POST">...'; /* etc */---------        -es donde imprimo el input para hacerle comentarios a los post y pasa que cada vez que esribo un comentario sale un nuevo input junto a ese comentario,como arreglo eso?

Comment: Amigo estoy pensando hacerlo mas facil(pienso).En vez de hacer que los comentarios salgan debajo de cada post,incluire un boton que al clicar me abra un modal con los comentarios de ese post.Creo que es mas organizado,pero no esta de mas que me muestresun ejemplo con dos consultas SQL.

Comment: Yo, personalmente, prefiero trabajar con la segunda solución porque suelo usar [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) para "pintar" el HTML, por lo que dentro de la plantilla implemento las secciones y subsecciones (por ejemplo temas y sus comentarios) como dos bucles `foreach` anidados. He editado mi respuesta para corregir el tema del formulario, es confuso interpretar tu HTML y definir claramente sus bloques porque la tabulación usada no me ayudó mucho. Edito: en cuanto tenga un hueco te pongo un ejemplo implementado con dos consultas independientes.